# Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module + no module named Django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

*I know that the question has already been asked here. I've read tons of answers, but nothing helped.*

I'm using virtualenv (/root/eb-virt); my Django project is called mediar. All public files are stored in /var/www/html/xxx.com/public_html/

From error log:

```
[Sun Oct 16 18:40:11.737747 2016] [:error] [pid 27659] [client 128.75.240.205:60486] mod_wsgi (pid=27659): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/xxx.com/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Oct 16 18:40:11.737808 2016] [:error] [pid 27659] [client 128.75.240.205:60486] mod_wsgi (pid=27659): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/xxx.com/django.wsgi'.
[Sun Oct 16 18:40:11.745983 2016] [:error] [pid 27659] [client 128.75.240.205:60486] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Oct 16 18:40:11.746153 2016] [:error] [pid 27659] [client 128.75.240.205:60486]   File "/var/www/html/xxx.com/django.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
[Sun Oct 16 18:40:11.746165 2016] [:error] [pid 27659] [client 128.75.240.205:60486]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Sun Oct 16 18:40:11.746191 2016] [:error] [pid 27659] [client 128.75.240.205:60486] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

My apache2.conf:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers 4
    MinSpareServers 20
    MaxSpareServers 40
    MaxClients 200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4500
</IfModule>


LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/xxx.com/public_html/mediar/mediar/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/xxx.com/public_html:/root/eb-virt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/

<Directory /var/www/html/xxx.com/public_html/mediar/mediar/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

My xxx.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.com
  ServerName  xxx.com
  ServerAlias www.xxx.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxx.com/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/xxx.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/xxx.com/log/access.log combined
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/xxx.com/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

And, finally, my django.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os, sys 

PROJECT_ROOT = '/var/www/html/xxx.com/' 
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT) 

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mediar.settings' 

import django.core.handlers.wsgi 
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I've tried

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

, it didn't help.

What should I do?

Comment: maybe in `django.wsgi` use `print(sys.version, sys.__file__)` to see which Python is used by server. Probably it doesn't use `virtualenv`

Comment: The ``/root`` directory generally can only be read by the ``root`` user. The user that Apache runs as would not be able to see inside of that directory. Do not put application code or virtual environments under ``/root``.

Comment: so did you solve the problem? i'm facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I would first try using the right python shebang in your wsgi file.  Shouldn’t it be something like the following?

```
#!/root/eb-virt/bin/python
```

And then the second thing would be to explicitly add the virtualenv to the `sys.path` append in the wsgi file

```
sys.path.append('/root/eb-virt/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
```

Comment: Fixed it, but nothing changed.

Comment: And just making sure, you restarted/reloaded apache after making the change?

Comment: I restarted it.

Comment: The shebang line is completely ignored by mod_wsgi. That isn't what dictates the Python version/installation being used.

Comment: Thanks, @GrahamDumpleton!  @sophie, you can refer to one of Graham’s other posts:  http://serverfault.com/questions/108067/how-do-i-find-the-python-executable-that-my-server-is-using for extra troubleshooting tips.  Also, he is an author/contributor of `mod_wsgi`.